# Detailed reputation view in the network profile

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, network-profile

I really find the reputation tab in the Stack Overflow profile useful.  Although I think that graphs in the reputation tab of the network profile are cool, I would like to have a view that is similar to the one in the Stack Overflow profile (at least the "by post"/"by time" ones), with events unified from all of my SE accounts (of course).